# как обратиться сразу ко всем объектам в листе Java

Tags: java, list

У меня есть пять кассиров

```
    List c = new ArrayList();
    Cashier c1 = new Cashier("Name_1", "SureName_1", "Username_1", "Password_1", +333);
    Cashier c2 = new Cashier("Name_2", "SureName_2", "Username_2", "Username_2", +334);
    Cashier c3 = new Cashier("Name_3", "SureName_3", "Username_3", "Password_3", +222);
    Cashier c4 = new Cashier("Name_4", "SureName_4", "Username_4", "Password_4", +555);
    Cashier c5 = new Cashier("Name_5", "SureName_5", "Username_5", "Password_5", +777);
```

как можно обратиться к ним, не перебирая каждого по отдельности?

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (username.equals(c[i].getUserName) && password.equals(c[i].getPassword)) {
           
        }
    }
```

пробовал таким способом, но выдает ошибку по поводу c[i]

Comment: `c.get(i)` ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Вы лучше скажите, что вы хотите сделать. Я так понимаю, вы хотите найти кассира, который будет подходить по имени и паролю?

Comment: Да, именно так. Если логин и пароль верные, то дальше он должен предоставлять меню(я это в коде убрал, чтобы не сбивать)

Answer (score 0):

```
Cashier c = list.stream().filter(cashier -> cashier.getName.equals(neededName) && cashier.getPassword.equals(neededPass)).findAny().orElse(null);
```

Фильтруем, находим рандомный(если есть), если нет null

Вот а еще список не работпет как массив: чтобы получить по индексу, пишите `list.get(index);`